# WSO2 ESB not roll backing in transcation with MySQL

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying transaction management in wso2 esb. I have a single database and a proxy to test transaction management, success case is working properly, but failure case it is not roll backing.

My Proxy:

```html
<proxy name="a" transports="http https jms" startOnLoad="true">
      <description/>
      <target>
         <inSequence>
            <send>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
               </endpoint>
            </send>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
            <transaction action="new"/>
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="text" value="** Reporting to the Database esbdb**"/>
            </log>
            <dbreport useTransaction="true">
               <connection>
                  <pool>
                     <dsName>jdbc/db</dsName>
                  </pool>
               </connection>
               <statement>
                  <sql>delete from company1 where name =?</sql>
                  <parameter xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd"
                             xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"
                             expression="//m0:return/m1:symbol/child::text()"
                             type="VARCHAR"/>
               </statement>
            </dbreport>
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="text" value="** Reporting to the Database esbdb1**"/>
            </log>
            <dbreport useTransaction="true">
               <connection>
                  <pool>
                     <dsName>jdbc/db</dsName>
                  </pool>
               </connection>
               <statement>
                  <sql>INSERT into company2 values (?,'c4',?)</sql>
                  <parameter xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd"
                             xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"
                             expression="//m0:return/m1:symbol/child::text()"
                             type="VARCHAR"/>
                  <parameter xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd"
                             xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"
                             expression="//m0:return/m1:last/child::text()"
                             type="DOUBLE"/>
               </statement>
            </dbreport>
            
            <transaction action="commit"/>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
         <faultSequence>
            <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="Transaction Action" value="Rollbacked"/>
            </log>
            <transaction action="rollback"/>
            
         </faultSequence>
      </target>
   </proxy>
```

My master-datasource.xml

```html
<providers>
  <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
</providers>

<datasources>

  <datasource>
    <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
    <jndiConfig>
      <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
      <configuration>
        <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
        <username>wso2carbon</username>
        <password>wso2carbon</password>
        <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
        <maxActive>50</maxActive>
        <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
        <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
        <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
        <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
      </configuration>
    </definition>
  </datasource>
  <datasource>
    <name>DS1</name>
    <jndiConfig>
      <name>jdbc/db</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
      <configuration>
        <dataSourceClassName>com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean</dataSourceClassName>
        <dataSourceProps>
          <property name="xaDataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</property>
          <property name="uniqueResourceName">jdbc/db</property>
          <property name="xaProperties.databaseName">esb_sp_sample</property>
          <property name="xaProperties.user">root</property>
          <property name="xaProperties.password">root</property>
          <property name="xaProperties.URL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/esb_sp_sample</property>
          <property name="poolSize">10</property>
        </dataSourceProps>
      </configuration>
    </definition>
  </datasource>
```

What could be the problem?

Note: I have also tried with https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Transaction+Mediator+Example having one database and 2 tables in it, but with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the

```
<send/>
```

Tag at the end of your fault sequence. Your fault sequence should be as follows.

```
     <faultSequence>
        <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="Transaction Action" value="Rollbacked"/>
        </log>
        <transaction action="rollback"/>
        <send/>
     </faultSequence>
```

Comment: even when it is there it is not working. It is a bug in 4.8.1 https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3581